# Virtualbox Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: virtualbox

In my Ubuntu 13.04 Virtualbox cannot install the extension package.

```
ErrorInstallazione dell'Extension Pack
/home/.../..../Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.12-84980.vbox-extpack non riuscita
The installer failed with exit code 1: Fontconfig warning: &quot;/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf&quot;, line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated..

Codice 'uscita: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Componente: ExtPackManager
Interfaccia: IExtPackManager {3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554}
```

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 2):

To install the extension package, download it from the virtualbox.org website.

Open a terminal and go to an arbitrary directory, then enter

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.12/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.12-84980.vbox-extpack
```

After the download finished, enter

```
sudo VirtualBox ./Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.12-84980.vbox-extpack
```

Virtualbox will start and ask you to accept the license. Scroll down and accept it.
The restart the application.